# Do p2pk and SIGHASH_SINGLE still working nowadays?

Tags: signature, p2pk, sighash

Seems like p2pk - pay to public key may be working or not in modern wallet apps. Is it still working or not?

EDIT: Can old p2pk addresses be used to move balance to new addresses (for example bc1q...)?

The same about SIGHASH_SINGLE - is there any Python library that supports this hash type today?

EDIT: And is there wallet app which supports it currently?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "working"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both P2PK and SIGHASH_SINGLE are still consensus valid and accepted by Bitcoin Core's default mempool policy. SIGHASH_SINGLE was even included in the Taproot soft fork for use in signatures in a Taproot spend.

As for using these, [python-bitcoinlib](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib) provides enough low level utilities that you can create and spend P2PK outputs and create SIGHASH_SINGLE signatures.

---

> p2pk addresses

There is no such thing as a P2PK address. They do not have an address type. You can create P2PK outputs, but there is no address type for instructing other people to create P2PK outputs that you can spend.